# Connected components of $\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb R^4 \mid xy+zt=2\}$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I want to find connected components of $H=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb R^4 \mid xy+zt=2\}$ and $H^c$, I put that in canonical form, i.e., $x^2-y^2+z^2-t^2=1$. How do I proceed from here? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x^2+z^2=:r^2$, $\>y^2+t^2=:s^2$. Then $r^2-s^2=1$, which is an arc of a hyperbola in the first quadrant of the $(r,s)$-plane. This arc can be parametrized as
$$r=\cosh u,\quad s=\sinh u\qquad(u\geq0)\ .$$
In all we obtain the following parametrization of your space $H$:
$$x=\cos\phi \cosh u, \quad z=\sin\phi \cosh u, \quad y=\cos\psi \sinh u, \quad t=\sin\psi \sinh u$$
with $\phi\in{\mathbb R}/(2\pi)$, $\>\psi\in{\mathbb R}/(2\pi)$, $\>u\in{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$. It is now obvious that $H$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The given hyper quadric is homeomorphic to $S^1$x$\mathbb R^2$, so is connected !

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: you can try to define a homeomorphism between $H$ and $S^1$x$\mathbb R^2$

Comment: What would the homeomorphism be in this case?